# Replacing newline character in Genexus

Tags: genexus

How can I replace newline character in a string with a space?

I tried this:

```
&myVar = &myVar.Replace(NewLine(),' ')
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself the solution:

```
&myVar = &myVar.Replace(Chr(10),' ')
```